# Negative numbers in Zmod?

Tags: sage

I'm doing the following in sage:

```
sage: Zp = Zmod(101)
sage: Zp(5)
5
sage: Zp(-1)
100
sage: Zp(100)
100
```

I understand that -1 = 100 mod 101, but I would like for sage to output -1 instead of 100 in both instances.

More generally, when working in Zmod(p), I would like the output to be in the interval (-p/2, p/2].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since IntegerMod_int is implemented in Cython for speed, you can't change this behavior at runtime.  The easiest way to get the feature you want is to change the *repr* function defined at sage/rings/finite_rings/integer_mod.pyx, line 1462 (at least, that's the line number in 5.0-beta12).  Replace it with something like

```
def _repr_(self):
    x = self.lift()
    modulus = self.parent().modulus()
    if x <= modulus // 2:
        return str(x)
    else:
        return str(x-modulus)
```